# Cannot load type HttpListener in simple Grapevine server example

Tags: c#, grapevine

I am trying to use Grapevine to implement a simple C# REST server. I am using Xamarin Studio on OSX. I pulled Grapevine 4.0.0.195 as a package.

However, when I try to run the example given on https://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/, I get this error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.HttpListener' from assembly 'Grapevine,
>   Version=4.0.0.195, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   at
>   Grapevine.Server.RestServer..ctor () [0x00006] in
>   <5da3c1fcf3364795b3df98bfc8b714aa>:0   at TestServer.MainClass.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/blah/Projects/Test/TestServer/Program.cs:12

I inspected the Grapevine assembly and found that `HttpListener` is indeed present.

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using Grapevine.Server;

namespace TestServer
{
    public sealed class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            using (var server = new RestServer())
            {
                server.Start();
                Console.ReadLine();
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not used Xamarin Studio before. I'll get it installed on a Mac and see if I can duplicate this.

Comment: From what I can tell, Xamarin lacks support for the `ExtendedProtectionSelector` property of `System.Net.HttpListener`. The first milestone in 2017 is for multiplatform support, and this may be an issue that we need to address them. Meanwhile, ask this question in our [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/sukona/Grapevine), as I know there are some people there who are using Grapevine with Mono.

Comment: I've logged an issue for this [here](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/issues/157)

Comment: There is an alpha version of Grapevine 4.1 up right now that should resolve this issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into the same issue and and discovered the same response as Scott Offen (thank you for your awesome work btw!) mentioned about ExtendedProtectionSelector.

So I went back to his previous version and I was able to make grapevine work in xamarin using grapevine version 3.1.0

It wont work right out of the box either( I was building for ios, idk if you would run into the same issues for android).  It will give you some errors about logging so I did Ctrl+F everywhere in his code about logging and changed it. I pretty much commented out everything in EventLogger.cs

Then in RESTServer, wherever there was a EventLogger to report the error, i simply changed it to Console.Writeline to describe the error when debugging.

Good luck!

Comment: Better than nothing! BTW, the `EventLogger` is gone in 4.0 and is being replaced soon with an optional provider pattern, so you can manage logging however you like. Thanks for providing this workaround.