# Running Grapevine REST server in Mono Docker container

Tags: c#, rest, docker, mono, grapevine

I´ve built a simple REST server with [Grapevine](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine) which runs perfectly with windows environment.
Now I want to run the .exe (with the Grapevine.dll) in an Docker Container with mono.
My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mono:latest
COPY . /boerse
RUN output="$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)"
CMD [ "mono", "/boerse/Boerse.exe", "$output" ]
```

When the Docker container starts, following error message occurs:

```
Error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.HttpListener' from assembly 'Grapevine, Version=4.0.0.195, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at Boerse.BoersenApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002f] in <407ced228a394aa7b9fc2fa883a239a9>:0
TypeRef ResolutionScope not yet handled (57) for .ExtendedProtectionSelector in image /boerse/Grapevine.dll
Could not load signature of Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.HttpListener:get_ExtendedProtectionSelectorDelegate due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100003a assembly: type:ExtendedProtectionSelector member:<none>
TypeRef ResolutionScope not yet handled (57) for .ExtendedProtectionSelector in image /boerse/Grapevine.dll
Could not load signature of Grapevine.Interfaces.Server.IHttpListener:get_ExtendedProtectionSelectorDelegate due to: Could not resolve type with token 0100003a assembly: type:ExtendedProtectionSelector member:<none>
```

All the needed DLL´s are copied into the container. 
Anybody knows how to run Grapevine in a Docker container or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are running into the same problem as [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087072/cannot-load-type-httplistener-in-simple-grapevine-server-example). I'm working on a fix for it, but it will be January before it gets released.

Comment: I've logged an issue for this [here](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/issues/157)

Comment: Please try this again using the latest version (4.1.0-alpha0) and let me know if that resolves the issue.